# How to format a Float number in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, formatting

In SQLite I need to format a number to display it with the thousand separator and decimal separator. Example: The number `123456789` should be displayed as `1,234,567.89`

What I did partially works because it does not display the thousand separator as I expected:

```
select *, printf ("U$%.2f", CAST(unit_val AS FLOAT) / 100) AS u_val FROM items;
```

`u_val` shows: `U$1234567.89` but I need `U$1,234,567.89`

Comment: Since version [3.18](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_18_0.html), thousands separators are supported, but only for integers.

Comment: @CL.: Yes, my `unit_val` field is an integer where I make a CAST to become a float field while displaying the data. How do I display the thousands separator in an Integer field?

Comment: `%,d`, but that would not work after the conversion. You'd have to output the cents separately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is one way that you could accomplish the result:-

```
select *, printf ("U$%.2f", CAST(unit_val AS FLOAT) / 100) AS u_val FROM items;
```

Could become :-

```
SELECT 
*, 
CASE
    WHEN len < 9 THEN myfloat 
    WHEN len> 8  AND len < 12 THEN substr(myfloat,1,len - 6)||','||substr(myfloat,len - 5)
    WHEN len > 11 AND len < 15 THEN substr(myfloat,1,len -9)||','||substr(myfloat,len-8,3)||','||substr(myfloat,len-5)
    WHEN len > 14 AND len < 18 THEN substr(myfloat,1,len - 12)||','||substr(myfloat,len -11,3)||','||substr(myfloat,len-8,3)||','||substr(myfloat,len-5)
END AS u_val
FROM   
    (
        SELECT *, length(myfloat) AS len
        FROM
            (
                SELECT *,printf("U$%.2f",CAST(unit_val AS FLOAT) / 100)) AS myfloat
                FROM Items
             )
    )
```

The innermost SELECT extracts the original data plus a new column as per your orginal SELECT.

The intermediate SELECT adds another column for the length of the new column as derived from **unit_val** via the printf (this could have been done in the first/innermost SELECT, getting this value simplifies (in my opinion) the outermost SELECT, or you could use multiple `length(myfloats)` in the outermost SELECT).

### RESULT - Example

The following is the result from a testing (source column is **myfloat**) :-

[image]

- The highlighted columns being the original columns.
- The circled data being the result.
- The other 2 columns are intermediate columns.

### Edit

As you've clarified that the input is an integer, then :-

```
SELECT *,'U$'||printf('%,d',(unit_val/100))||'.'||CAST((unit_val % 100) AS INTEGER) AS u_val FROM Items
```

would work assuming that you are using at least version 3.18 of SQLite.

### Correction

Using the SQL immediately above if the value of the last part (the cents) is less than 10 then the leading 0 is dropped. So the correct SQL is. Note for simplicity the CAST has also been dropped and rather than concatening the **`.`** it has been added to the `printf` formatter string so :-

```
SELECT 
    'U$' || 
    printf('%,d', (unit_val / 100)) ||
    printf('.%02d',unit_val % 100) 
    AS u_val
FROM Items
```

Or as a single line

```
SELECT 'U$' || printf('%,d', (unit_val / 100)) || printf('.%02d',unit_val % 100) AS u_val FROM Items
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The result is the same I want, but I find it a bit complex to get the thousand separator and I imagine this is one of the possible solutions. I'm assuming that SQLite should have some function for this without having to convert the values to strings and then separate everything into parts. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Now it works with your second SQL statement. But I'm still not getting a little detail. Example: For the `12.3` number, I would like it to be formatted as `12.30`, but I am not able to format the last CAST in the SQL statement, so the decimal part is always represented by two digits. Is it possible to do that? Thank you again @MikeT .

Comment: It works like that: `SELECT *,'U$'|| printf('%,d', ((qtde * unit_val)/100)) || '.' || substr(CAST(((qtde * unit_val) % 100) AS INTEGER) || '00', 1, 2) AS u_val FROM itens;`

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting that result. **`12.3`** would be stored as **`1230`** so `CAST((unit_val % 100) AS INTEGER)` (as would `(unit_val % 100)` so no real need for `CAST` unless column type is REAL when it acts to correct) will result in 30 not 3. If you were storing 123 then you'd get 1.23. You haven't by any-chance used 10 instead of 100 as the divisor?

Comment: @wBB what's qtde? (value and type if know, where does it come from (hard-coded or column)) That may change matters. SQLite will, if I recall correctly, take type of left so perhaps that is a factor.

Comment: Sorry, I entered too much information that I copied from my tests. This `qtde` field means `length` or `quantity` (INTEGER). I was also adding zeros to the left and the correct one would add on the right side of the cents. The correct SQL is `SELECT 'U$'|| printf('%,d', (unit_val / 100)) || '.' || substr('00' || CAST((unit_val % 100) AS INTEGER), -2, 2) AS u_val FROM itens;`. It works fine! Thank you.

Comment: In my tests I also needed to change the decimal separator from '.' to ',' and separator of thousands from ',' to '.' using the `replace` function. I could not do this using the locale settings. It's already working with the `replace` function, but it seems to me an incorrect way... Thanks @MikeT

Comment: Nothing you can do about the separators other than replace. However padding cents with left 0 when less than 10 cents (plus a trimming/re[lacing ||'.') can be done with `SELECT 'U$'|| printf('%,d', (unit_val / 100))||printf('.%02d',unit_val % 100) as u_val` so printf instead of substr. The %,d appears to be special case hence why you can't use anything else (at least **`.`** and thus why you can't swap, so you need replace).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion:

```sql
WITH cte AS (SELECT 123456789 AS unit_val)
SELECT printf('%,d.%02d', unit_val/100, unit_val%100) FROM cte;
```

The Common Table Expression is just there to supply a dummy value, in the absence of variables.

The `%,d` format adds thousands separators, but, as many have pointed out, only for integers. Because of that, you will need to use the `unit_val` twice, once for the integer part, and again to calculate the decimal part.

SQLite truncates integer division, so `unit_val/100` gives you your dollar part. The `%` operator is a remainder operator (not strictly the same as “mod”), so `unit_val%100` gives the cents part, as another integer. The `%02d` format ensures that this is always 2 digits, padding with zeroes if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I came here looking for a simple example of how to use `printf()` in SQLite and I really appreciate the concision of this answer.